# Tool tip balloon is not showing for controls in win forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows form application where some controls are hidden at first and visible on some condition.
Sometimes tool tip balloon is not visible.
I have below code in constructor,

```
ToolTip toolTipBalloon;
toolTipBalloon.AutoPopDelay = 15000;
toolTipBalloon.InitialDelay = 1500;
toolTipBalloon.IsBalloon = true;
toolTipBalloon.ReshowDelay = 100;
toolTipBalloon.ToolTipTitle = "Setting";
toolTipBalloon.Popup += new System.Windows.Forms.PopupEventHandler(this.toolTipBalloon_Popup);
```

In event handler:

```
private void toolTipBalloon_Popup(object sender, PopupEventArgs e)
{
  // Set title of tooltip to control's accessible name or text
  Control ctrl = e.AssociatedControl;

  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ctrl.AccessibleName))
    toolTipBalloon.ToolTipTitle = ctrl.AccessibleName;
  else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ctrl.Text))
    toolTipBalloon.ToolTipTitle = ctrl.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to assign the tooltip to the control at some point.

```
toolTipBalloon.SetToolTip(ctrl, "Message");
```

You can also add multiple controls with diffrent messages to the same tooltip.

```
toolTipBalloon.SetToolTip(btnStart, "Start the thingy!");
toolTipBalloon.SetToolTip(lblSpeed, "You're going thiiiis fast.");
toolTipBalloon.SetToolTip(txtName, "Enter your super hero name.");
```

Comment: I have added this code for all controls in the form. But still some times tool tip balloon is coming.

Comment: @Ravindra What do you mean by "coming"? I'm unsure what your actual problem is to be honest, sorry. Could you try to give a more detailed explanation?

Comment: I have assigned toolTipBallon.SetToolTip(chkBoxName,"Hello") in form constructor. This check box control will not be visible at first time. Based on some conditions check box control will be visible. This tool tip balloon is NOT coming everytime. Sometime control shows shows tool tip balloon some time not. I am unsure why it is happening like this.